# Python install module issue

Tags: python, python-3.x

On my `Linux` box I have python 2.x and 3.x. I have to install some module like `request` only on python 3.x.

How i can force `pip` to install module for only python 3.x?

I tried command `pip install requests` then it install on python 2.x not 3.x

I have to keep both version of python due to some old script so I can not get rid of completely python 2.x

Comment: You need to add a location of Python3 binary in the PATH env. variable before python2

Answer (score 1):

Running `pip3 install` should cover this. Or you can run `python3 -m pip install`, to call the pip module instead of the executable.

Comment: I dont have ```pip3``` installed . how i can install this on my linux?

Comment: You can use `apt-get` to install pip3. But I actually prefer `python3 -m pip`.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using "pip3" command? This can be installed with apt-get install python3-pip. Pip3 is the same as pip, but only works with python3

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `pip3` instead or `pip`.
`pip3` refers to Python 3.x and `pip` to Python 2.x